# virsh: networkGetBridgeName error

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, libvirt

I'm trying to configure foreman. So far I connected foreman to one of our KVM hosts. Specifically, this is a libvirt and we are using virsh for managing it.

When I try to create VM in foreman I'm getting the following error:
`2019-08-26 12:56:48.641+0000: 23751: error : networkGetBridgeName:4007 : internal error: network 'direct' does not have a bridge name.`

My network configuration looks like that:

```
virsh net-dumpxml --network direct
```

```
<network>
  <name>direct</name>
  <uuid>799cc56d-4c09-4963-83f6-dadb5c03bbaa</uuid>
  <forward dev='br0' mode='bridge'>
    <interface dev='br0'/>
  </forward>
</network>
```

Do you know what should I do with that? In foreman I'm getting the following error:

```
Error loading interfaces information: Internal Server Error
```

One more config file which can help:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 
# Generated by dracut initrd
DEVICE="br0"
IPV6INIT="no"
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=172.26.106.89
NETMASK=255.255.224.0
GATEWAY=172.26.96.1
NAME=br0
DEFROUTE=yes
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has an error in it, and because of that I have no idea how you got it into libvirt to begin with.

To define a network corresponding to an existing bridge on the host that libvirt does not manage, you need to have a `<bridge>` element inside the `<forward>` element. But your XML does not.

You should not have:

```
    <interface dev='br0'/>
```

You should instead have:

```
    <bridge name='br0'/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Our previous config was generated from puppet and no idea why it worked properly for the past few years.

Comment: It's possible that it actually wasn't working, and libvirt just ignored it. The network definition for a bridge not managed by libvirft is optional anyway.